# Finding Density Function of Transformation

Tags: probability-distributions

> Let $Y$ be uniformly distributed over the interval $(−1, 3)$. Find the probability density function
>   of $U = Y^2$.

Attempted solution:

We know that

$$
Y=\begin{cases}
1/4 && -1 \leq y \leq 3\\
0 && \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

We find the CDF of $U$ using $Y$
$$
P(U \leq u) = P(Y^2 \leq u) = P(-\sqrt u \leq Y \leq \sqrt u)
$$
$$
= \int_{-\sqrt u}^{\sqrt u}\frac{1}{4}dy = \frac{\sqrt u}{2}
$$

Therefore

$$
f(u) =  \frac{d}{du}\frac{\sqrt u}{2} = \frac{1}{4\sqrt u} \qquad 0 \leq u \leq 9
$$

However, the answer is:

$$
f(u) =  \begin{cases} \frac{1}{4\sqrt u} && 0 \leq u < 1\\
\frac{1}{8\sqrt u} && 1 \leq u \leq 9
\end{cases}
$$

Logically, since Y is between -1 and 3, this makes sense to me since there are two values of Y for which U will be between 0 and 1 for each value, and only one value of Y for which U is between 1 and 9.

Despite this, why didn't the computation pick up on this? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The statement of the problem, that you apparently  copied, says "U= Y" but your calculation uses "$U= Y^2$.  Which is it?

Comment: My mistake. It should be $U = Y^2$. Sorry.

Comment: The square function is not injective on $(-1,3)$ so taking the inversion as you do requires some care.

Answer (score 1):

If $1<u<9$, then

$$P(-\sqrt{u}\leq Y < \sqrt{u}) = P(-1\leq Y \leq \sqrt{u}) = \int_{-1}^{\sqrt{u}} 1/4 dy $$

This should solve your problem. Remember that Y has 0 density outside of the interval [-1,3].

Comment: Wouldn't $Y=0$ satisfy your second probability range? If so, then $U = Y^2 = 0$ but $U \not \in (1,9)$.

Comment: @BrydenC What you are saying does not make the answer wrong. The answer given by Leander Tilsted Kristensen is correct.